# Select group style in gridview

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am developing an app metro for windows 8. I use GridApp (xaml) project, but I want to use different group style in each section.

My code is:

```
public class GroupTemplateSelector : GroupStyleSelector
{

    public GroupStyle NewsItemGroupStyle { get; set; }
    public GroupStyle NormalGroupStyle { get; set; }

    protected override GroupStyle SelectGroupStyleCore(object group, uint level)
    {
        // a method that tries to grab an enum off the bound data object

        if (level == 3)
        {
            return NewsItemGroupStyle;
        }
        else
        {
            return NormalGroupStyle;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Unexpected group type"); 

    }
}
```

I use this class to selector group style and XAML

```
<!-- NewsItemGroupStyle -->
<GroupStyle x:Key="NewsItemGroupStyle">
    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    <GroupStyle.Panel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.Panel>
</GroupStyle>


<!-- NormalItemGroupStyle -->
<GroupStyle x:Key="NormalGroupStyle">
    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                <Button
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                    Content="{Binding Title}"
                    Background="Blue"
                    Click="Header_Click"
                    Style="{StaticResource TextButtonStyle}"
                    />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    <GroupStyle.Panel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.Panel>
</GroupStyle>

<!-- selector -->
<common:GroupTemplateSelector 
    x:Key="groupSelector"
    NewsItemGroupStyle="{StaticResource NewsItemGroupStyle}"
    NormalGroupStyle="{StaticResource NormalGroupStyle}" />
```

but the style group changes all at once.

Comment: You can see if this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/63a5d82c-1ad2-4e24-bfb4-122d5551c5f0/) on MSDN answers your question.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and so does everyone on this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/winappswithcsharp/thread/5f12273f-e000-4c96-a4bc-6ccc18a104a0

Comment: Guys, look at the last entry in this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/809464a1-a152-472b-8b38-9538bc5975ee TL;DR: `GroupStyleSelector` is *not designed* to support different group styles at the same grouping level. Note to self: ABANDON SHIP, ABANDON SHIP!

Answer (score 0):

As Lvsti pointed out, GroupStyleSelector is only able to change the style at each *level*. e.g. all level 0 groups will have the same style but all level 1 groups could have a different style. It's not currently possible to have two different groups at level 0 with different styles. In fact, it appears that the last style returned for any group at the same level is applied to all groups at that level. It is unfortunate, but that's the current design.

Dev support, design support and more awesome goodness on the way: http://bit.ly/winappsupport

Comment: wait, I'm clearly missing something here. how would you have more than a level 0 group? I've only ever seen the grouped gridview used to show the groups and their items (as in the GroupedItemsView template). Can you show me an example of a grouped gridview that a) has more than one level and b) uses a groupstyleselector? thank you!